# Angular 2 proper implementation of ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

So, I have been trying to implement ControlValueAccessor by following several guides, but I get stuck on this error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'rise-datepicker'.
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IconModule } from '../icon/icon.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DatePickerComponent } from './datepicker.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, IconModule, FormsModule],
  exports: [DatePickerComponent],
  declarations: [DatePickerComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class DatePickerModule { }
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

import { DatePicker } from './datepicker.model';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'rise-datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker.component.css'],
  providers: [{ 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, DatePicker, ControlValueAccessor {

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    //this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    //this.propagateTouch = fn;
  }

  value: string;

  [...]
}
```

Template

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker__input" (click)="toggle()" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Implementation

```
<rise-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date"></rise-datepicker>
```

Angular version is 2.0.1.

If you can, please, let me know what is wrong!

Comment: Try to import the FormsModule in your app.module.ts

Comment: @Sakuto uh... sometimes it's just that silly. Thank you very much.

Comment: read [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83)